# Only 1 Thread accessing RestController Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am using Spring Rest API to create application. I am facing one strange problem that only 1 Thread is able to access the Controller method at a time.
Below is code snippet.

If multiple rest service is called i.e. getSample, at that time only 1 Thread is executing this method and rest threads are waiting for the completion.Its same like working of synchronized method

Thanks in advance.

```
@RestController
Class Sample {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/controller/sample",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getSample(@RequestBody String input) {
        System.out.println("Hello World !!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share, how are you concluding that it is working like synchronized method?

Comment: Probably the caller is synchronized? Have you tried with multiple browser tabs and a GET mapping?

Comment: This is weird. Please share modified spring files, if any, and/or application.properties, pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my answer after reading the following blog.
https://studiofreya.com/2012/02/06/spring-mvc-how-to-build-a-thread-safe-controller/

Rest controller/Controller of Spring is a bean by default with singleton scoped.
Upon component scan it will just create controller bean with default scope.

To make it mutithreded we need to change the scope!

The solution to the problem will be the following:

1. Annotate Controller with @Scope(“request”) or @Scope(“session”)
2. Move private variable into one of the methods or save it in session or model.

Read the link shared.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is multithered use something like this to test it

```
@RestController
Class Sample {

@RequestMapping(value = "/controller/sample",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object getSample(@RequestBody String input) {
    System.out.println("Hello World !!")
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.println("GoodBye World !!")
}
}
```

call multiple time and you will see some 'Hello World !!' first.

Comment: No.... After GoodBye World!! is printed then Hello World come for second thread

Answer (score 0):

> REST controller is multi-threaded **by default**, as the
>   `DisptcherServlet` handles multiple requests from the clients
>   concurrently and serves using the respective controller methods. You
>   can refer the request handling flow [at official Spring MVC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc)

If, in your case, first thread blocks every other incoming request, then you have some sort of configuration, JVM or resources issue. Probably your web-server or application don't have enough threads in the thread pool or your firewall is fooling around.

Regardless, most likely, problem is out there.